# Javascript only hides element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make social sidebar, which can be hidden when clicked on arrow.It hides by margin-left. I tried toggling classes, if statements, but it only hides it and doesn’t show after second click. This is my code now:

javascript-jQuery:

```
$(".socialArrow").click(function () {
    $(".arrowLeft").toggleClass("fa-angle-left fa-angle-right");
});
var wrapper = document.getElementById("socialWrapper");
$(".fa-angle-left").click(function () {
    wrapper.style.marginLeft = ("-80px");
});

$(".fa-angle-right").click(function () {
    wrapper.style.marginLeft = ("0px");
});
```

html:

```
<div class="socialContainer">
    <ul id="socialWrapper">
        ...some links...
    </ul>

    <span class="socialArrow">
        <i class="arrowLeft fa fa-angle-left"></i>
    </span>

</div>
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Sorry for my English , I’m not from UK/US.

Comment: use this demo http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_toggle

Comment: You add event listeners (click) to elements which don't exist yet (.fa-angle-right). You could improve your code by have just 1 click handler. Within the click method, you check if .fa-angle-right exists and based on that you either add or remove the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with toggleClass, this way:

```
$(".socialArrow").click(function () {
    $("#socialWrapper").toggleClass("closed");
});
```

and CSS:

```
#socialWrapper.closed {
    margin-left: -80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So when the first $(".fa-angle-right") selector runs, there is no such class item yet, so the click() isn't applied to anything.  You create an element with that class later.  So you really need to rerun those click() assignments after your class change.  Like:

```
function setClick() {
    $(".fa-angle-left").click(function () {
        wrapper.style.marginLeft = ("-80px");
    });
    $(".fa-angle-right").click(function () {
        wrapper.style.marginLeft = ("0px");
    });
}

$(".socialArrow").click(function () {
    $(".arrowLeft").toggleClass("fa-angle-left fa-angle-right");
    setClick();
});

var wrapper = document.getElementById("socialWrapper");
```

This way, your click event gets reset every time the classes change.